# Why is this md5 function returning null sometimes?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting a couple of values from a mysql database, combining and hashing them. Sometimes the result is null. Anyone know why?

First we fetch an associative array representing the row.

```
$results = dal::query("select foo, email from wtf where email = ?", $_GET["email"], "row");
```

Then we check for truthy results and hash.

```
if($results["foo"] && $results["email"]){
   $whyisthisnullsometimes = md5($results["foo"] . $results["email"]);
   $url = "https://example.com/dostuff.php?thing={$whyisthisnullsometimes}";
}
```

$whyisthisnullsometimes occasionally is just null. Not sure why.

The url is appended to an email message and sent. Users are hitting this link, which would not exist if ($results["foo"] && $results["email"]) evaluates to false.

wtf.foo is char 32 and wtf.email is varchar 250. collation is latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: that is easy :-)  `if($results["foo"] && $results["email"]){` if your condition is `false` you have `$whyisthisnullsometimes` not defined and php interprets it as `null`. for further information you should post bigger fragment of your code :-)

Comment: An md5 hash can never be null.... are you sure you're not displaying `$whyisthisnullsometimes` when `$results["foo"]` or `$results["email"]` are empty?

Comment: @Alex I checked that. $whyisthisnullsometimes is empty within the if block. Wish it was that easy

Comment: @bingo, can you update the question with the values that are causing it to output null?

Comment: @MarkBaker I just double checked this. I am building a string within this conditional. I'll post some more code.

Comment: you did not close your md5() it should be `md5($results["foo"] . $results["email"])`

Comment: `md5` is a simple function which only depends on its inputs and will always return the same output. If you can get it to produce `null`, this should be easily reproducible by giving it the right (or wrong) input. Debug your code, show us what values you're putting into `md5` to make it return `null`.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, this must be an issue with the hyperlink in the email then.

Comment: @deceze but it does return null if there is no argument passed : http://ideone.com/N1LBp4

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/md5) says `md5` ***always*** returns a 32-character hexadecimal number. `null` is not one of its return values. Experimentation shows that it will **produce an error and return `null`** if you omit all parameters. As long as you give it *a* parameter, even an empty string, it will return an MD5 hash. Concentrate your investigations on other avenues, this function is most likely not your problem.

Comment: Yes, I rewrote my comment to cover that. However, even an empty string works, and since you're using the concatenation operator as an argument, at the very least you're passing an empty string. Heck, even `null` produces a result. You should also see an error in your error log if you were passing no arguments.

Comment: @deceze Going to check some other things and add some more details to my logging efforts. What makes this difficult is that it rarely occurs. The vast majority of the time, this routine works as expected.

Comment: Then you'll have to add some more debugging and logging code and wait for it to reoccur. As I see it, there are two possibilities: 1) you have discovered a bug in PHP which should be reported on the bug tracker, but for which you need a lot of hard data to make it reproducible first; 2) you have a bug in some other part of your code and you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

That is quick answer:

when

```
if($results["foo"] && $results["email"]){
```

your condition is false you have `$whyisthisnullsometimes` not defined and php interprets it as `null`.

For further information you should post bigger fragment of your code :-)

Comment: I checked this. This is not the issue.

Comment: I track your comments. See no proofs yet ;-) The fragment you posted is not complete. Inculde some `echo` in `If` section, create `else` branch to set your `$url = "NO RESULT FROM SQL"`  for example. you can try to add `exit` or `die` just after your `if...else` to see the values.

Comment: What makes this hard to test is that it is only null sometimes. The vast minority of the time, so having trouble reproducing.

Comment: there is nothing hard or difficult. you just need to learn good habits to set vars proper way. so your `$whyisthisnullsometimes` for example should be initialazed as `$whyisthisnullsometimes = '';` before `if`. And your `$url` should be set in `else` flow for the `$results["foo"] && $results["email"]` false. that will help you always understand what happened in your code and where variable values came from.